# Finding image src using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, automation, puppeteer

I am trying to get the src of the first Google image search result using Puppeteer(class="bRMDJf islir).
I have tried using the parent class as well as the image class itself:

```
const imgURL = await page.$eval('img.rg_i.Q4LuWd[src]',img => img.src);
```

```
const imgURL = await page.$eval('.bRMDJf.islir img',img => img.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue here is that your selectors are wrong.

```
const imgURL = await page.$eval('.bRMDJf.islir img', img => img.src);
```

Should be:

```
const imgURL = await page.$eval('.bRMDJf.islir > img', img => img.src);
```

Also if you want to get the image src from an element you have selected before, instead of selecting for the element from within the page context (using `page.$eval`), or if you want to select using xpath, you can use getProperty on the element instead.

Should be something like this:

First select the element:

- CSS

  ```
  const element = await page.$('.bRMDJf.islir > img');
  ```
- XPath - Select the first element that is `img` with an attribute `src` that is contained within any element with the attribute `class` with value `bRMDJf islir`.

  ```
  const element = (await page.$x('//*[@class="bRMDJf islir"]/img[@src]'))[0];
  ```

Then get the value of the property `src` from the element:

```
const imgSrc = (await element.getProperty('src'))._remoteObject.value;
```